# How to select files/folders based on input name prefix match in nautilus instead of start searching?

Tags: nautilus, search, filename

When one types on the keyboard in a view of a directory in `nautilus`, it either starts searching or to select the first file/folder matching the input with a prefix in the file's/folder's name. I've been searching a availalbe options in the settings dialog, but it doesn't seem to be configurable and change from release to release (in Ubuntu 14.10-beta1 it's searching, in 14.04 it was prefix matching and in 13.10 searching again, as far as I remember). How to configure prefix matching?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to activate type-ahead-find with the following gsettings modification:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences enable-interactive-search true
```

Source: http://www.webupd8.org/2014/01/nautilus-type-ahead-find-feature.html